# Update dataframe if not equal

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, in which I want to know whether they are different based on column as a key otherwise will update the one that is different so they become equal

```
val TMP_SITE = spark.load("jdbc", Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:System/maher@//localhost:1521/XE", "dbtable" -> "IPTECH.TMP_SITE"))
      .withColumn("SITE",'SITE.cast(LongType))

val local_pos = spark.load("jdbc", Map("url" -> url, "dbtable" -> "pos")).select("id","name")

TMP_SITE.printSchema()
local_pos.printSchema()

val join = TMP_SITE.join(local_pos, 'SITE === 'id, "inner")
```

```
root
 |-- SITE: long (nullable = true)
 |-- LIBELLE: string (nullable = false)

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

the result of joining is

```
  |id |name                  |SITE|LIBELLE               |
+---+----------------------+----+----------------------+
|51 |Ezzahra               |51  |Ezzahra               |
|7  |BENIKHALLED           |7   |BENIKHALLED           |
|15 |Kram                  |15  |Kram                  |
|54 |El Mourouj            |54  |El Mourouj            |
|11 |LE BARDO              |11  |LE BARDO              |
|29 |Mini M Ksar said      |29  |Mini M Ksar said      |
|69 |ZAGHOUAN              |69  |ZAGHOUAN              |
|42 |BEB EL KHADHRA        |42  |BEB EL KHADHRA        |
|73 |Zaouit Kontech        |73  |Zaouit Kontech        |
|87 |Aouina                |87  |Aouina                |
|64 |Sousse I I            |64  |Sousse I I            |
|3  |SAHRA CONFORT : KORBA |3   |SAHRA CONFORT : KORBA |
|34 |SOUKRA SQUARE         |34  |SOUKRA SQUARE         |
|59 |SAHRA CONFORT : ZARZIS|59  |SAHRA CONFORT : ZARZIS|
|8  |Jerba                 |8   |Jerba                 |
|22 |Moknine               |22  |Moknine               |
|28 |RDAYEF                |28  |RDAYEF                |
|85 |MONASTIR ABSORBA      |85  |MONASTIR ABSORBA      |
|16 |BARDO HANAYA          |16  |BARDO HANAYA          |
|35 |Mini M Agba           |35  |Mini M Agba           |
+---+----------------------+----+----------------------+
```

I did this

```
val temp = join.withColumn("changes", when($"LIBELLE" === $"name", lit("nothing")).otherwise("need an update"))
```

I got this

```
|id |name                  |SITE|LIBELLE               |changes       |
+---+----------------------+----+----------------------+--------------+
|51 |Ezzahra               |51  |Ezzahra               |nothing       |
|7  |BENIKHALLED           |7   |BENIKHALLED           |nothing       |
|15 |Kram                  |15  |Kram                  |nothing       |
|54 |El Mourouj            |54  |El Mourouj            |nothing       |
|11 |LE BARDO              |11  |LE BARDO              |nothing       |
|29 |Mini M Ksar said      |29  |Mini M Ksar said      |nothing       |
|69 |ZAGHOUAN              |69  |ZAGHOUAN              |nothing       |
|42 |BEB EL KHADHRA        |42  |BEB EL KHADHRA        |nothing       |
|73 |Zaouit Kontech        |73  |Zaouit Kontech        |need an update|
|87 |Aouina                |87  |Aouina                |nothing       |
|64 |Sousse I I            |64  |Sousse I I            |nothing       |
|3  |SAHRA CONFORT : KORBA |3   |SAHRA CONFORT : KORBA |nothing       |
|34 |SOUKRA SQUARE         |34  |SOUKRA SQUARE         |nothing       |
|59 |SAHRA CONFORT : ZARZIS|59  |SAHRA CONFORT : ZARZIS|nothing       |
|8  |Jerba                 |8   |Jerba                 |nothing       |
|22 |Moknine               |22  |Moknine               |need an update|
|28 |RDAYEF                |28  |RDAYEF                |nothing       |
|85 |MONASTIR ABSORBA      |85  |MONASTIR ABSORBA      |nothing       |
|16 |BARDO HANAYA          |16  |BARDO HANAYA          |nothing       |
|35 |Mini M Agba           |35  |Mini M Agba           |nothing       |
+---+----------------------+----+----------------------+--------------+
```

I do not why it said that they need to be updated because they are the same.
Although it should say nothing for all of them, because they are equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a `dataframe`, its quite easy to play with the `columns` and `rows`.

So you have following `dataframe` after your `join`

```
+----+---------------------+----+---------------------+
|SITE|LIBELLE              |id  |name                 |
+----+---------------------+----+---------------------+
|48  |Mini M Boumhel       |48  |Mini M Boumhel       |
|67  |Lac                  |67  |Lac                  |
|992 |test2                |992 |test                 |
|44  |KAIROUAN             |44  |KAIROUAN             |
|61  |Tunis                |61  |Tunis                |
|9001|MONOPRIX             |9001|MONOPRIX             |
|3   |SAHRA CONFORT : KORBA|3   |SAHRA CONFORT : KORBA|
|37  |Mini M Borj Lozir    |37  |Mini M Borj Lozir    |
|83  |Jendouba             |83  |Jendouba             |
|12  |Bigro                |12  |Bigro                |
+----+---------------------+----+---------------------+
```

You can create another column with the logic you have written but by using `when` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val temp = join.withColumn("changes", when($"LIBELLE" === $"name", lit("nothing")).otherwise("need an update"))
```

`temp` `dataframe` would be

```
+----+---------------------+----+---------------------+--------------+
|SITE|LIBELLE              |id  |name                 |changes       |
+----+---------------------+----+---------------------+--------------+
|48  |Mini M Boumhel       |48  |Mini M Boumhel       |nothing       |
|67  |Lac                  |67  |Lac                  |nothing       |
|992 |test2                |992 |test                 |need an update|
|44  |KAIROUAN             |44  |KAIROUAN             |nothing       |
|61  |Tunis                |61  |Tunis                |nothing       |
|9001|MONOPRIX             |9001|MONOPRIX             |nothing       |
|3   |SAHRA CONFORT : KORBA|3   |SAHRA CONFORT : KORBA|nothing       |
|37  |Mini M Borj Lozir    |37  |Mini M Borj Lozir    |nothing       |
|83  |Jendouba             |83  |Jendouba             |nothing       |
|12  |Bigro                |12  |Bigro                |nothing       |
+----+---------------------+----+---------------------+--------------+
```

now you can just use `filter` method on `dataframe` as

```
temp.filter($"changes" === "need an update").show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+----+-------+---+----+--------------+
|SITE|LIBELLE|id |name|changes       |
+----+-------+---+----+--------------+
|992 |test2  |992|test|need an update|
+----+-------+---+----+--------------+
```

You just need to play with the columns by using `select`, `groupBy`, `aggregations`, `filters` and other inbuilt functions or by using `udf` functions etc etc. You can even convert into `rdd` and `tuples` too as you did in your example.